# Print out column row count in python3 from postgresql column

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, discord.py

so is there a good way to print out how many rows are in a column so it will only print out a number like "20"?.

```
 amountofdb = bot.pg_con.fetch("SELECT verifieduser FROM antiraidverified")
```

Comment: There is enough information provided to really say, namely where `pg_con` is coming from? If `psycopg2` is the underlying driver there is `rowcount` on [Cursor](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html).

Comment: its from import asyncpg

Comment: `len(amountofdb)`?